# jquery dynamic carousel

Tags: jquery, carousel

here is my problem ,and I need your advices which jquery carusel plugin is more convenient, maybe some of you already made something like this.

There should be four rows of carousels. And each in sequence should be dynamically loaded.
For example, when I click on item from first carousel row, in the second carousel the appropriate items should be loaded. And the same for the third and fourth carousel rows.

Thanks, in advance

Answer (score 2):

try jQuery Carousel

http://www.thomaslanciaux.pro/jquery/jquery_carousel.htm