# jQuery slider suggestions

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, image-gallery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery dynamic carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076967/jquery-dynamic-carousel)

I am at blockage in my road - I am looking out for a jQuery plugin that allows me to slide through an image gallery using either next/prev arrows and thumbnails of the images in the gallery. This bit is fairly simple to find, however the complication comes in that the images in the gallery are not of uniform size, and need to centered horizontally and vertically within a block level element regardless of their width and height.

Is there any jQuery plugin out that supports my needs? I don't really want to have to go out and build my own.

Comment: [www.codecanyon.net](http://www.codecanyon.net) should have what you need

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is nivoslider, check this:

http://nivo.dev7studios.com/demos/4/

And it's free!